# polymorphism and generic class

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

I have a function that return derived class in generic response, the signature of the function is common to some derived classes:

classes defenition:

```
 public class BaseClass
 {
   int {get;set;}
 }
 public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
 {
    int b {get;set;}
 }
```

Function in Base Class:

```
 public class BaseRepository 
 {
     public virtual GenericClass<BaseClass> Func()
     {
        return null;
     }
 }
```

Function in derived class:

```
public class Repository : BaseRepository
{

     public override GenericClass<BaseClass> Func()
     {
         var response  = new GenericClass<DerivedClass> ();
         //TODO
         return response;
      }
 }
```

I get this error message:

```
 cannot implicitly convert type 'GenericClass<DerivedClass>' to 
 'GenericClass<DerivedClass>'
```

Comment: DO you mean the error is from GenericClass<DerivedClass> to GenericClass<BASEClass> maybe? Also question: where is class definition GenericClass?

Comment: Yes, I get the error on derived class. when I return from function the derived class instead of base class,. It doesn't meter what is the generic class' can be also List

Comment: If it doesn't work implicitely... maybe try explicitely?

Comment: Without any variance hints, a `GenericClass<DerivedClass>` cannot be returned as a `GenericClass<BaseClass>` otherwise you could return a `List<Dog>` as a `List<Animal>` and the caller could call `list.Add(cat)` on this list.

Comment: Post a [mcve] with the `GenericClass` included.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to map GenericClasses with different generic Parameters.

The generic class doesn't know how to cast them.

```
// Is not allowed..
List<object> l = new List<string>();

// Use a method to explain your class how to convert.
List<object> l = new List<string>().ToList<object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

As kara mentioned you can't map GenericClasses with different generic Parameters.
But you can do something similar to below example.

Assuming that your GenericClass looks like:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    T myProperty { get; set; }

    public GenericClass(T myProperty)
    {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }
}
```

your Func in DerivedClass might look like

```
public override GenericClass<BaseClass> Func()
{
   var response = new GenericClass<BaseClass>(this);
   //TODO
   return response;
}
```

Comment: tanks, but my case is different, the classes is response from service, not of the response class, the func is under other class, see in the question, I edited